# Speed up aggregation on large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I currently have a database with about 270 000 000 documents. They look like this:

```
[{
    'location': 'Berlin',
    'product': 4531,
    'createdAt': ISODate(...),
    'value': 3523,
    'minOffer': 3215,
    'quantity': 7812
},{
    'location': 'London',
    'product': 1231,
    'createdAt': ISODate(...),
    'value': 53523,
    'minOffer': 44215,
    'quantity': 2812
}]
```

The database currently holds a bit over one month of data and has ~170 locations (in EU and US) with ~8000 products. These documents represent timesteps, so there are about ~12-16 entries per day, per product per location (at most 1 per hour though).
My goal is to retrieve all timesteps of a product in a given location for the last 7 days. For a single location this query works reasonable fast (150ms) with the index `{ product: 1, location: 1, createdAt: -1 }`.

However, I also need these timesteps not just for a single location, but an entire region (so about 85 locations). I'm currently doing that with this aggregation, which groups all the entries per hour and averages the desired values:

```js
    this.db.collection('...').aggregate([
      { $match: { { location: { $in: [array of ~85 locations] } }, product: productId, createdAt: { $gte: new Date(Date.now() - sevenDaysAgo) } } }, {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            $toDate: {
              $concat: [
                { $toString: { $year: '$createdAt' } },
                '-',
                { $toString: { $month: '$createdAt' } },
                '-',
                { $toString: { $dayOfMonth: '$createdAt' } },
                ' ',
                { $toString: { $hour: '$createdAt' } },
                ':00'
              ]
            }
          },
          value: { $avg: '$value' },
          minOffer: { $avg: '$minOffer' },
          quantity: { $avg: '$quantity' }
        }
      }
    ]).sort({ _id: 1 }).toArray()
```

However, this is really really slow, even with the index `{ product: 1, createdAt: -1, location: 1 }` (~40 secs). Is there any way to speed up this aggregation so it goes down to a few seconds at most? Is this even possible, or should I think about using something else?
I've thought about saving these aggregations in another database and just retrieving that and aggregating the rest, this is however really awkward for the first users on the site who have to sit 40 secs through waiting.

Comment: In the $group stage you are doing some conversions (date to string) and concatenating string to a date. I suspect this might be causing a performance issue. Instead of doing a "to string and then concat" try creating the date using the `$dateFromParts`, like: `$dateFromParts: { 'year' : { $year: "$dt" }, 'month' : { $month: "$dt" }, 'day': { $dayOfMonth: "$dt" }, 'hour' : { $hour: "$dt" } } }`. _[ Continued ...]_

Comment: _[ Continued from previous comment]_:  _In addition_, (1) if possible run the query with the first match stage only, and then with the group stage and clock the time at each run; this can give some idea about where the issue is, _and_ (2) run the `explain()` with the query and in the generated query plan see if the index is being applied as expected. NOTE: In the previous comment I used `dt` instead of `createdAt`in the code snippet.

Comment: Remove `sort`, it should speed up

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for the suggestions. Adding $dateFromParts increased performance a little, altough the most time takes the match part (90%~ at least). I've managed to speed it up by hinting `{ item: 1, scannedAt: -1, slug: 1 }` as it used the other one instead (I assume because $in doesn't affect the cardinality assumptions of mongo). So it now runs 50-60% faster, which is still really slow.  
Any other suggestions to make the matching faster? I've thought about adding a precalculated `region` key to the data, altough im not sure if the performance is that much better than $in

Comment: @Valijon that did almost nothing

Comment: @nn3112337 How many documents filtered by `$match` condition? Share your filtered data and we may try different strategy.

Comment: @Valijon The match stage returns about 5000-7000 documents.

Comment: Not sure if it will change much for your case. Could you try creating index `{ location: 1, product: 1, createdAt: -1 }` instead ?  While you are there could you please run the explain and share the output for both indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some ideas which can benefit the querying and performance. Whether all these will work together is matter of some trials and testing. Also, note that changing the way data is stored and adding new indexes means that there will changes to application, i.e., capturing data, and the other queries on the same data need to be carefully verified (that they are not affected in a wrong way).

**(A) Storing a Day's Details in a Document:**

Store (embed) a day's data within the same document as an array of sub-documents. Each sub-document represents an hour's entry.

*From:*

```
{
    'location': 'London',
    'product': 1231,
    'createdAt': ISODate(...),
    'value': 53523,
    'minOffer': 44215,
    'quantity': 2812
}
```

*to:*

```
{
    location: 'London',
    product: 1231,
    createdAt: ISODate(...),
    details: [ { value: 53523, minOffer: 44215, quantity: 2812 }, ... ]
}
```

This means about ten entries per document. Adding data for an entry will be pushing data into the details array, instead of adding a document as in present application. In case the hour's info (time) is required it can also be stored as part of the details sub-document; it will entirely depend upon your application needs.

The benefits of this design:

- The number of documents to maintain and query will reduce (per
  product per day about ten documents).
- In the query, the group stage will go away. This will be just a
  project stage. Note that the  `$project` supports [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators-in-other-stages) `$avg` and `$sum`.

The following stage will create the sums and averages for the day (or a document).

```
{ 
    $project: { value: { $avg: '$value' }, minOffer: { $avg: '$minOffer' }, quantity: { $avg: '$quantity' } }
}
```

Note the increase in size of the document is not much, with the amount of details being stored per day.

**(B) Querying by Region:**

The present matching of multiple locations (or a region) with this query filer: `{ location: { $in: [array of ~85 locations] } }`. This filter says : `location: location-1, -or- location: location-3, -or- ..., location: location-50`. Adding a new field , `region`, will filter with one value matching.

The query by region will change to:

```
{ 
  $match: { 
      region: regionId, 
      product: productId, 
      createdAt: { $gte: new Date(Date.now() - sevenDaysAgo) } 
  } 
}
```

The `regionId` variable is to be supplied to match with the region field.

Note that, both the queries, "by location" and "by region", will benefit with the above two considerations, **A** and **B**.

**(C) Indexing Considerations:**

The present index: `{ product: 1, location: 1, createdAt: -1 }`.

Taking into consideration, the new field `region`, newer indexing will be needed.  The query with region cannot benefit without an index on the region field. A second index will be needed; a compound index to suit the query. Creating an index with the region field means additional overhead on write operations. Also, there will be memory and storage considerations.

**NOTES:**

After adding the index, both the queries ("by location" and "by region") need to be verified using `explain` if they are using their respective indexes. This will require some testing; a trial-and-error process.

Again, adding new data, storing data in a different format, adding new indexes requires to consider these:

- Careful testing and verifying that the *other existing* queries perform as usual.
- The change in data capture needs.
- Testing the new queries and verifying if the new design performs as expected.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great suggestion, this reduces document size significantly and with that the indexes now all fit into the RAM! Querying regional data with this and a `{ product: 1, createdAt: -1, region: 1 }` index reduces the query time down to 4-6secs. I assume there is no way to push this under 1 second, unless I go for precomputing?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly your aggregation is pretty much as optimized as it can get, especially if you have `{ product: 1, createdAt: -1, location: 1 }` as an index like you stated.

I'm not exactly sure how your entire product is built, however the best solution in my opinion is to have another collection containing just the "relevant" documents from the past week.

Then you could query that collection with ease, This is quite easy to do in Mongo as well using a [TTL Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/).

If this not an option you could add a temporary field to the "relevant" documents and query on that making it somewhat faster to retrieve them, but maintaining this field will require you to have a process running every X time which could make your results now 100% accurate depending when you decide to run it.